# detect if html select dropdown is in dropdown selected state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have HTML drop-downs;

Coded in the below format:

```
   <select name="State" id="State" class="required"/>
              <option value="">--Select State--</option>
              <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
   </select>
```

I have an error background image that appends to the `<select>` tag on error. But I would like to remove the background image, once the user has used the drop-down and has currently selected an available `option`.

So, when the drop down is open and any item is selected via `<option>` tag hide background image. I don't need help with hiding the background image per se'. Just the logic of detecting when an `option` has been selected.

I have tried starting with this logic

```
$('option:selected').css('background', 'none !important');
```

Here's the caveat you guys *may* be missing; if there is a scenario when the user toggles back to the default start state - *eg* in this case '*Select a State*' this background image must reappear / restore.

Comment: You are also closing your select tag improperly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a change event on the State dropdown. So whenever the value is not empty, it will hide the error message.

```
$('#State').change(function() {
    if(this.value !== '') {
        //hide error
        console.log('hide');
    } else {
        //show error
        console.log('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: this would fail if there is an option other than the default one with value = ""

Comment: OP's HTML code specifies that the default option has a value="".

Edit -- I see what you're saying now. But I don't see why you would have another value of "". This would be an invalid option anyhow.

Comment: I agree but it was just a thought to share in case you do have such scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use an image but its the same idea. I see you are applying styling directly to the element. I would recommend just using a class to apply the image and removing the class when you don't need the image any more:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/oLrckqzj/

HTML:

```
<select name="State" id="State" class="required">
    <option value="">--Select State--</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById('State');
select.addEventListener('change',
    function () {
        if (this.value != '') {
            this.classList.remove('required');
        }
        else {
            this.classList.add('required');
        }
    }
);
```

Also you had this

```
<select name="State" id="State" class="required"/>
```

Which should be:

```
<select name="State" id="State" class="required">
```

And with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/oLrckqzj/1/

```
var $select = $('#State');
$select.on('change',
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() != '') {
            $this.removeClass('required');
        }
        else {
            $this.addClass('required');
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect whether an option is selected or not, you can do the following:

```
   $('select').change(function()
    {
        if($(this)[0].selectedIndex == 0 && $(this).val() == "") // check if value is empty and index of the selected option is not zero.
           alert("not selected");
       else 
           alert("selected");
    });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/WTkqn/300/

Answer (score 0):

This will be fired when an option has been selected, assuming it is different from the currently selected option. It will not fire when the select menu is opened, though. You can probably use on 'click' for that.

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    console.log("changed: ", this, e);
});
```